# Can I mix php and asp.net on the same web page to call a crystal report?

Tags: php, asp.net

I need a simple asp.net popup that is embedded on a php page that will then call a crystal report. Is this possible? Or is this possible with php?

Comment: Not really. The best you could do is load a HTML page and then do separate AJAX calls to PHP and ASP. That doesn't sound like what you want tho